# HPLIP gui and VPNC on Lubuntu

Tags: lubuntu, vpnc, hplip

Both of these questions are related to avoiding dependencies from other desktop environments.

I'm using a HP printer on Lubuntu. I installed HPLIP from synaptic without the GUI on my notebook and WITH the GUI on my desktop. I think the GUI is qt-based. Is it recommended to install the GUI when running a non-qt desktop environment like LXDE? Does it provide any additional functionality like a resume-function when the printer runs out of paper?

I've used vpnc on Ubuntu to access university vpn-network. Is it recommended using the same packages on Lubuntu? I think there's a KDE version called kvpnc.

Answer (score 1):

Download and install HPLIP directly from the HP OPEN SOURCE website. http://hplipopensource.com/hplip-web/downloads.html

Click on DOWNLOAD HPLIP. Find the downloaded file and right click on it and select PERMISSIONS. Select MAKE EXECUTABLE. Click OK.

Right click on the file again and select OPEN then EXECUTE. Follow the instuctions.

*Reason it works is mainly because it detects and installs dependencies that the apt-get or software center version won't.